# Failing the iOS build on AppCilrcle platform after adding the flavors in flutter project

Tags: flutter, xcode, command-line-interface, fastlane

I already did the building setps for only single environment, but now I am trying to build the iOS app for multiple environment (prod, dev). For that I have added the required code and settings in AppCirle. Also I had requested to AppCircle team to assist me, but they were also unable to detect the issue. So here I am posting the same problem. Appreciate for the help.

This is the Xcode setup for multiple environment:-

[As you can see for prod and dev environment I have setup it with respective schemes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAFTz.png)

In AppCircle, the settings for building the app using flavors are added.
[In Additional /Extra Argument I have added the "--flavor prod" command to build for production and in XcodeBuild extra flag "-flavor prod"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvyIc.png)

but it's failing this kind of setup and error shows like
"Error (Xcode): Runner has conflicting provisioning settings. Runner is automatically signed, but code signing identity Apple Development: Talentserv Mobility (LW39GY5CW3) has been manually specified. Set the code signing identity value to "Apple Development" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the Signing & Capabilities editor.
.../_appcircle_temp/Repository/ios/Runner.xcodeproj
Encountered error while building for device."
here is the log file.
[After build done, it was failed for flutter build for iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMBzy.png)

The final solution from AppCircle team is, I will have to search proper command for Xcode CLI. because Xocde and Xcode CLI commands are act different for build. I did so much research on that why is this failing but nothing has found.

Please suggest me if there any other command or way to build the iOS app using flavor command in AppCircle.

Answer (score 0):

this issue is resolved now. In project path instead of Runner.xcproject, I have replace it by Runner.xcworkspace in Configuration section of AppCircle. Thank You.